# Earth Engine image exists but won't display

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, naip

I am trying to extract some images from the NAIP series from the Earth Engine (using Python API):

```py
pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-113.344628,33.31913499)
img = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ') \
        .filterDate('2003-01-01', '2005-01-01') \
        .filterBounds(pt) \
        .first()
```

When I query the date of the returned image, I get a non-zero respose (2004-06-28):
print(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format().getInfo())

But when I try to show the image, nothing is displayed.

However, if I change the date range in the filterBounds above to (2003 to 2008), the date returned is 2007-06-16 and the image is displayed correctly.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: This is strange. The image is georegistered out in the Pacific ocean. I'll file a bug with the data team. https://code.earthengine.google.com/80ff1e7a1133ef73a5134649b2bd032b

Comment: Thanks @JustinBraaten. I have a bunch of points that give me the same behavior: they return a date but no image. It also looks like that the problematic points return the date 2004-06-28 (not sure if that applies to all of them).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I'll append it to the bug description. Not sure when I'll hear back, but will update this thread when I do.

Comment: Could you provide the ids of other bad images?

Comment: Sorry @SimonIlyushchenko I was out of town and couldn't answer this. These are too many points and I am not sure how to make a list of them. Now that I check again, it looks like all of those points have somehow been changed (I guess due to what was done about the bug report). But now all of those points return EEException: Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required when I query their date. Also, when I try to display the images, it returns EEException: Expression does not evaluate to an image. I am displaying in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed USDA/NAIP/DOQQ/n_4211317_sw_12_1_20040628:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/36c93b69d7a8848a4ebe1e9d0aecfea3

Comment: Thanks Simon for the answer! However, I am still confused. The coordinates in the query are for a point in Arizona, while the image in your answer is now in Idaho! Also, when I request its date print(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format().getInfo()), it returns an error: EEException: Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required.

Comment: There are no images for Arizona for your time period. The misplaced image had a bad 
footprint encompassing the whole world, which is why you used to get it back. Now that the image is in the right location, there are no more matches.